# Stack Smashing in Java Interposer

Tags: java, c, linux, stack, interposing

I am writing a Java interposer to modify network communication related system calls. Basically, I want to modify the IP and port of the intended recipient.

The code works correctly on my laptop, but on university PC, it gives a **stack smashing error** as:

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: java terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x45)[0xb7702dd5]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0xffd8a)[0xb7702d8a]
/home/mwaqar/vibe/ldinterposer_2.so(+0x28e4)[0xb77c98e4]
/home/mwaqar/vibe/ldinterposer_2.so(connect+0x9c5)[0xb77c9093]
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/libnet.so(+0xceff)[0x8b226eff]
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/libnet.so(Java_java_net_PlainSocketImpl_socketConnect+0x4c1)[0x8b227c51]
```

The relevant code (interposition of **connect** system call) is as follows:

```
int connect(int fd, const struct sockaddr *sk, socklen_t sl)
{
struct sockaddr_in      *lsk_in  = (struct sockaddr_in *)  sk;
struct sockaddr_in6     *lsk_in6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *) sk;

struct sockaddr_in      addr4;

unsigned int            len;
int                     nbytes, oport, tport, ret, i;
char                    ip_address[30];
char                    buffer[1024];   
char                    tempBuffer[1024];   

if((lsk_in->sin_family == AF_INET) || (lsk_in->sin_family == AF_INET6))
{
    if(lsk_in->sin_family == AF_INET)
    {
        oport = ntohs(lsk_in->sin_port);
        memcpy(&addr4.sin_addr.s_addr, &lsk_in->sin_addr.s_addr, sizeof(addr4.sin_addr.s_addr));
    }
    else if(lsk_in->sin_family == AF_INET6)
    {
        oport = ntohs(lsk_in6->sin6_port);
        memcpy(&addr4.sin_addr.s_addr, lsk_in6->sin6_addr.s6_addr+12, sizeof(addr4.sin_addr.s_addr));
    }

    memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));
    sprintf(buffer, "%s%c%s%c%i", NAT_VM_CONNECT_RULE, NAT_VM_DELIMITER, (char *)inet_ntoa(addr4.sin_addr), NAT_VM_DELIMITER, oport);

    nbytes = send(sock, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
    if(DEBUG_MODE)
        fprintf(stdout, "[LD_INTERPOSER] Sent[%s]\n", buffer);

    memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));
    nbytes = recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);

    fprintf(stderr, "[LD_INTERPOSER] Received CONNECT [%s]\n", buffer);

    memset(ip_address, '\0', sizeof(ip_address));
    int pos = strrchr(buffer, NAT_VM_DELIMITER) - buffer;

    strncpy(ip_address, buffer, pos);
    ip_address[pos] = '\0';
    tport = atoi(buffer + pos + 1);

    if(lsk_in->sin_family == AF_INET)
    {
        lsk_in->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip_address + 7);
        lsk_in->sin_port = htons(tport);
    }
    else if(lsk_in->sin_family == AF_INET6)
    {
        inet_pton(AF_INET6, ip_address, &(lsk_in6->sin6_addr));
        lsk_in6->sin6_port = htons(tport);
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "[LD_INTERPOSER] IP[%s], Port[%d] for VM[%s]\n", ip_address, tport, vm_ip);
}

int my_ret = real_connect(fd, sk, sl);
fprintf(stderr, "Done\n");
return my_ret;
}
```

Here, **sock** is a socket that I have initialized in "constructor" of the shared library.

The program works correctly and prints **Done**. On the last (return) line, it gives the stack smashing error. I have no idea what is causing this.

Comment: Sorry, updated the code.

Comment: Stack smashing error is caused by the built-in mechanism that checks for possible buffer overflow errors. Check that you never write more bytes to `buffer` or `tempBuffer` that their respective size.

Comment: Never use `sprintf`, especially if you suspect overruns. I don't know if it's the cause of error here, but it's the first thing to fix.

Comment: Are you sure that `strrchr()` isn't returning `NULL`?

Comment: @buc: I am sure `buffer` and `tempBuffer` are not overflowing. Their capacity is 1024 bytes each and the max they hold is ~100 characters.

Comment: Did you try running this with gdb?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `strrcr` returns `NULL` in the line

```
int pos = strrchr(buffer, NAT_VM_DELIMITER) - buffer;
```

Then `pos` will be huge, and the following lines will read and write invalid addresses.

Always check the return value of functions (especially when they're run on data received from outside your program).

Also, as I wrote in my comment, never use `sprintf`. I can't tell if it fails, because I don't know what's `NAT_VM_CONNECT_RULE`. Even if you counted the bytes and know you're OK, you should still be careful and use `snprintf` instead.

Comment: I don't think the line you mentioned is the problem. The reply received is of the form `IP|port` (`NAT_VM_DELIMITER` is a character '|'). I have to separate these. If that statement was the problem, then line `fprintf(stderr, "[LD_INTERPOSER] IP[%s], Port[%d] for VM[%s]\n", ip_address, tport, vm_ip);` would not have printed correct (separate) IP and port. Also, I think if that statement was the problem, program would have terminated there instead of working till the second-last statement `fprintf(stderr, "Done\n");` of the function.

Comment: Maybe this isn't what caused the problem, but it is a bug. You should start by fixing the two bugs I showed you, and then try to debug it.

Comment: I have rectified all the bugs you mentioned. Still the same `*** stack smashing detected ***` output.